# SQL : Date Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

On the daily basis, I have to update a DateTime column in the table. The field should in the format '2019-04-30 00:00:00.000', It should be always the 'NextYear-04-30 00:00:00.000'. How do I write this function?

As I am running this update statement today i.e in 2018 so it should be '2019-04-30 00:00:00.000', If I run the update statement in 2019, it should be '2020-04-30 00:00:00.000'

```
For Example: This query is giving me '2018-04-30 00:00:00.000'
Select CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(20),DATEPART(year, getdate())) + '-04-30')
```

Thanks

Comment: The function you are looking for: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_dateadd.asp

Comment: `The field should in the format ` <= A `DateTime` does not have a format. A format only applies when you output the value to string so you (a human) can read it. You should also not persist this value as a string (varchar), it should be persisted as `Date` or `DateTime2`.

Comment: `UPDATE dbo.table SET column = DATEADD(YEAR, 1, '20190430');`? It's a `datetime` column so you don't need all of this string manipulation, formatting, a bunch of zeroes, etc. And you should avoid formats like `yyyy-mm-dd` because they can be interpreted as `yyyy-dd-mm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your same query, you can just encapsulate with a `DATEADD` function to add 1 year:

```
Select DATEADD(YEAR, 1, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(20),DATEPART(year, getdate())) + '-04-30'))
```

Produces output:

```
2019-04-30 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [DATEADD()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function.

```
UPDATE yourTable SET DateCol = DATEADD(year,1,DateCol)
```

Comment: This gives me select DATEADD(year,1,GETDATE())
2019-10-26 11:48:47.330

Comment: CAST it as DATE.

Comment: The OP doesn't want "this day next year" but "April 30th next calendar year"

Answer (score 0):

You can add one year in your table date column which you want to update as shown below -

```
update YourTable
set YourDateColumn = DATEADD(year, 1,YourDateColumn) 
where YourDateColumn <= GETDATE() --It will only update which has value less than next year. Remove or update it as required
```

As with your values

```
select DATEADD(year, 1,'2018-04-30 00:00:00.000')
```

Comment: So, in 2019 Should I update this code to select DATEADD(year, 1,'2019-04-30 00:00:00.000') ?? I want the year to be dynamic

Comment: This value of date for example '2019-04-30 00:00:00.000' be the dynamic value may be from your table column.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can also use a computed column. It will mean a loss of performance vs running a job updating a column once a day, but it will give you peace of mind as the job could fail and you not being made aware.

The function would be:

CAST(DATEADD(YEAR, 1, GETDATE()) AS DATE)

If this is something fed into a  report, I would use a sproc to generate the report and dynamically add a column populated with the function above.

If this is used in business I would also use sprocs and dynamically calculate the variable internally.

I see little use for a column always indicating the date in one year. It's just not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use below logic to get time as 00:00:00.000

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(DATEADD(YEAR, 1, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS DATETIME)
```

Outup:

```
2019-10-26 00:00:00.000
```

**EDIT**

use DATEFROMPARTS (added to sqlserver 2012)

```
SELECT CAST(DATEFROMPARTS ( YEAR(GETDATE())+1, 4, 30 )  AS DATETIME)
```

Output:

```
2019-04-30 00:00:00.000
```

DateFromParts Source:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: but my output should be '2019-04-30 00:00:00.000'